# What is the relation between CustomErrors web.config setting and azure app insights logging?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, azure-application-insights, custom-errors

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#prior-versions-support

> If the CustomErrors configuration is Off, then exceptions will be
> available for the HTTP Module to collect.

```
//If customError is Off, then AI HTTPModule will report the exception
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
                {   //or reuse instance (recommended!). see note above
                    var ai = new TelemetryClient();
                    ai.TrackException(filterContext.Exception);
                }
```

If IsCustomErrorEnabled then it will track exception. For IsCustomErrorEnabled to be true, customError must be ON. So why does it say - If customError is Off, then AI HTTPModule will report the exception?

Answer (score 3):

I think the comment in this Microsoft example is a bit misleading, here is what it means:

- If `CustomErrors` is `Off`, the Application Insights HTTP module will handle all the exceptions as expected. Application Insights HTTP module should be present in `web.config` `<modules>` section
- If `CustomErrors` is `On`, the Application Insights HTTP module will NOT be able to track exceptions, that is why we need a workaround with the custom attribute class

Therefore, the attribute example code uses the statement `if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)` to avoid logging exceptions twice: in the custom attribute and Application Insights HTTP module.

It would be clearer if the comment said something like this:

```
//The attribute should track exceptions only when CustomErrors setting is On
//if CustomErrors is Off, exceptions will be caught by AI HTTP Module
if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
{
    var ai = new TelemetryClient();
    ai.TrackException(filterContext.Exception);
}
```

Please note that all of the above is only relevant for MVC 4 and prior versions. Starting from MVC 5, Application Insights can collect unhandled exceptions automatically and no workarounds are required.

**UPDATE**: I suggested an improvement for [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#prior-versions-support) and it has been approved by the Azure docs team.